# ansible: How to change $HOME directory

Tags: ansible

I am running  `ansible 2.9.6` in my control machine `Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop`
to control single server `Ubuntu 16.04` server which doesn't have `/home/username/` directory.
I don't intend to create one aswell.

I am just trying to create a new folder "/usr/local/src/fromcontrolmachine" in slave machine from control machine

So I ran below command

```
 dinesh@dinesh-VirtualBox:/etc/ansible$ ansible all -u dira
 --become -m file -a "dest=/usr/local/src/fromcontrolmachine mode=755 owner=dira group=dira state=directory" -K
```

> BECOME password:

```
> 10.211.108.44 | FAILED! => {
>     "changed": false, 
>     "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 10.211.108.44 closed.\r\n", 
>     "module_stdout": "Could not chdir to home directory /home/dira: No such file or directory\r\n\r\n", 
>     "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
>     "rc": 1 }
```

I thought of changing the $Home directory by adding below line in
/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg. It just created an empty folder called `ansible`

```
 remote_tmp = usr/local/src/ansible
```

How to tell ansible to change the default `$Home` directory by pointing to other location than default `/home/dira` ?

I wanted to clear this annoying error
    "module_stdout": "Could not chdir to home directory /home/dira271641: No such file or directory

UPDATE:

Also tried creating playbook `pb.yml` & add `home_dir: /usr/local/src/ansible` as mentioned below.

```
---

- hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        home_dir: /usr/local/src/ansible
      become: true
    - name: ansible create directory example
      file:
        path: /tmp/devops_directory
        state: directory
```

When i run above using command `ansible-playbook pb.yml -K`

But it gives the same error as mentioned above.

UPDATE:
I tried `environment: HOME:`

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  environment: 
    HOME: /usr/local/src/ansible
  tasks:
  - name: ansible create directory example
    file:
      path: /tmp/devops_directory
      state: directory
```

Throws same error

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/dira: No such file or directory\r\n\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}}, "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding below line.

```
become_user: dira
```

solved this problem. Note: dira is my username. So replace your username instead.
So full playbook script will look like

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true
  become_user: dira
  environment: 
    HOME: /usr/local/src/ansible
  tasks:
  - name: ansible create directory example
    file:
      path: /tmp/devops_directory
      state: directory
```